# Analyse URL in JMeter test plan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

1. Is there a way to extract/analyse the target URL in a random JMeter test plan provided through a random source?
2. Also, a stretch goal is to identify the target service platform through this like Azure, AWS etc., is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is, you can use i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) like `prev.getUrlAsString()`
2. Theoretically it should be possible to extract the IP address from the URL and check whether it belongs to [Azure IP Range](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) or  [AWS IP range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download)

   ```
   InetAddress.getByName(prev.getURL().getHost()).getHostAddress()
   ```

Demo:

[image]

In be above examples `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance holding the result of the **prev**ious sampler execution, see the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

Comment: So, that means we'd need to add these post-processors for every sampler in the test plan? Also, would it work in case URL is fed runtime through JMeter properties/variables?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can add a single Post-Processor at the same level as all the Samplers (or above), see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more details. This way the Post-Processor will be applied to all Samplers it its scope. It will extract the current URL in the runtime, no matter of origin: hard-coded, redirect, correlation, parameterization, whatever.